# Цикл в каждом элементе прошлого цикла

Tags: python, циклы

```
while b < 33:
    b += 1
    while x < 33:
        x += 1
```

у меня вопрос, почему в этом коде в каждом элементе цикла б, не повторяется цикл х, где х увеличивается на 1

Comment: а никто его не сбрасывает меньше 33. тут же нет иннициализации

Comment: поставьте х=0 перед вторым while

Comment: спасибо, помогло